# How to view the Worklight Server database tables during development-time?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Can someone please tell me how to view/access the internal IBM worklight database tables, created in runtime(Eg., APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT, APP_SYNC_DATA, etc.). I want to know where and how they are stored. Or do we need to configure anything with respect to get the access to these internal tables. If yes, could you please elaborate the procedure. I am a newbie for worklight and right now using the IBM Worklight Development Server for understanding of Worklight stuffs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Worklight Studio (the Eclipse plug-in), Worklight uses a file system-based database (HSQL) that is not accessible. Technically, you could access it, but not during runtime because the database file will be locked, and it is possible only by using some other Eclipse plug-in to view its contents.

The database file is stored in this location:

> ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE\WorklightServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\72\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\PROJECT_NAME\APP_NAME\hsqldb

You **should not** access it this way.

To access the database tables in a sane and correct manner, you should manually create the Worklight database. To do so:

1. Install [MySQL database server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
2. Install some tool to view the database, such as [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/)
3. Create a "worklight" database
4. Create a database user, for example: username "worklight & password "worklight"
5. In your project's `server\config\worklight.properties` file, configure the project to use the "worklight" MySQL database you've created above

> ```
> ########################################################################
> # DB Settings [Development Only]
> ########################################################################
>
> # For MySQL
> #wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your-database-name
>
> #wl.db.username=your-username
> #wl.db.password=your-password
> ```

Now once you start the Worklight Server, and everything is properly configured, this database will be populated with the Worklight tables and you will be able to view their contents.

Comment: Thank you Idan... It worked!!! But I want to know what does each column of these tables describe. Could you please tell me where can I get this information.

Comment: Please take the time to go through the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center, you can find your answers there: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/admin/r_internal_ibm_worklight_database_tables.html?lang=en